# Netbeans scala javadocs missing in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, javadoc

I've been looking into scala lately and from the conciseness and language features I'm completely thrilled.

I have netbeans 8.0 running on ubuntu 12.04 and downloaded scala, edited netbeans.conf (netbeans_default_options="-J-Dscala.home=...), installed plugins from plugin manager inside netbeans (ALL OF THEM). Then, I created scala project (not maven one) and tried out autocomplete. It works, compiles, runs, however, it shows no document found in autocompletion.

This is how I added javadocs Tools > Scala platforms > javadoc tab

I tried adding following ways:

1. added the entire scala api doc zip from http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.2/scala-docs-2.11.2.zip
2. extracted the previous zip to scala-home folder under $SCALA_HOME/docs/javadocs/scala-docs-2.11.2 and added that
3. same as 2 but added $SCALA_HOME/docs/javadocs/scala-docs-2.11.2/api in netbeans

None of these pick up documentation! Of course, I could live without it, but it's such a killer for such a concise language where I could just find out stuff instantly from autocompletion. Also, I don't want to use eclipse special ide for scala because I don't want to throw out all the experience with netbeans out of the window and learn new IDE.

P.S. - Netbeans navigator also seem not to work in scala.

And I wonder why there's so little content on google for such a wonderful language?

Comment: I have to say that I'm envious.  I have netbeans 8.0 and scala 2.11.1 and the sbt etc installed, and building my hello world reports:The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/raz/NetBeansProjects/scala1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:238: Unknown target 'jvm-1.8'  any thought on how to fix that?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to fix that, just use IntelliJ IDEA with scala plugin, netbeans support for scala is pathetic :( It has documentation and everything working. I'll update this answer actually.

Comment: The problem you encountered is that the Ant builder was started. The plugin however supports sbt or Maven builds. The Ant configuration was not maintained and will be removed from the plugin in the next release of the plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Netbeans support for scala seems pathetic so I just decided to jump to IntelliJ IDEA. It was little bit of learning curve but I'm glad I did because now everything was working (autocomplete, documentation, awesome SBT support etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change to IntelliJ. Use the right build tool -sbt or Maven- and everything works fine.
In Netbeans you can use e.g. free Application Servers.